# Last password change date/time for user in Google Apps directory API

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to find the last password change date.  I see it in the admin console when editing a user:

[image: Google apps admin]

However, none of the metadata listings show an entry for the last password change date: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

```
  {
  "kind": "directory#users",
  "users": [
  {
   "kind": "directory#user",
   "id": "the unique user id",
   "primaryEmail": "liz@example.com",
   "name": {
    "givenName": "Liz",
    "familyName": "Smith",
    "fullName": "Liz Smith"
   },
   "isAdmin": true,
   "isDelegatedAdmin": false,
   "lastLoginTime": "2013-02-05T10:30:03.325Z",
   "creationTime": "2010-04-05T17:30:04.325Z",
   "agreedToTerms": true,
   "hashFunction: "SHA-1",
   "suspended": false,
   "changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
   "ipWhitelisted": false,
   "ims": [
    {
     "type": "work",
     "protocol": "gtalk",
     "im": "lizim@talk.example.com",
     "primary": true
    }
   ],
   "emails": [
    {
     "address": "liz@example.com",
     "type": "work",
     "customType": "",
     "primary": true
    }
   ],
   "addresses": [
    {
     "type": "work",
     "customType": "",
     "streetAddress": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
     "locality": "Mountain View",
     "region": "CA",
     "postalCode": "94043"
    }
   ],
   "externalIds": [
    {
     "value": "employee number",
     "type": "custom",
     "customType": "office"
    }
   ],
   "relations": [
    {
     "value": "susan",
     "type": "friend",
     "customType": ""
    }
   ],
   "organizations": [
    {
     "name": "Google Inc.",
     "title": "SWE",
     "primary": true,
     "customType": "",
     "description": "Software engineer"
    }
   ],
   "phones": [
    {
     "value": "+1 nnn nnn nnnn",
     "type": "work"
    }
   ],
   "aliases": [
    "lizsmith@example.com",
    "lsmith@example.com"
   ],
   "nonEditableAliases: [
    "liz@test.com"
   ],
   "customerId": "C03az79cb",
   "orgUnitPath": "corp/engineering",
   "isMailboxSetup": true,
   "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
  },
  {
   "kind": "directory#user",
   "id": "user unique ID",
   "primaryEmail": "admin2@example.com",
   "name": {
    "givenName": "admin",
    "familyName": "two",
    "fullName": "admin two"
   },
   "isAdmin": true,
   "isDelegatedAdmin": true,
   "lastLoginTime": "2013-02-05T10:30:03.325Z",
   "creationTime": "2010-04-05T17:30:04.325Z",
   "agreedToTerms": true,
   "hashFunction: "SHA-1",
   "suspended": true,
   "suspensionReason": "ADMIN",
   "changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
   "ipWhitelisted": false,
   "emails": [
    {
     "address": "admin2@example.com",
     "type": "work",
     "customType": "",
     "primary": true
    }
   ],
   "externalIds": [
    {
     "value": "contractor license number",
     "type": "custom",
     "customType": "work"
    }
   ],
   "relations": [
    {
     "value": "liz",
     "type": "friend",
     "customType": ""
    }
   ],
   "aliases": [
    "second_admin@example.com"
   ],
   "nonEditableAliases: [
    "admin@test.com"
   ],
   "customerId": "C03az79cb",
   "orgUnitPath": "corp/engineering",
   "isMailboxSetup": true,
   "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "next page token"
}
```

I'm specifically using C# and the google apps directory API.

Anyone know where this field is located and/or how to access it?